# apt-get: error while loading shared libraries:libapt-pkg

Tags: 12.04, command-line, apt, 64-bit

I am facing a problem which seems to be unsolvable. I am trying to resolve the issue but to my disappointment nothing seems to work. The problem I'm facing are as follows

1. Whenever I try to run `sudo apt-get install` or `sudo apt-get update`, I get the following error :

   ```
   apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: libapt-pkg.so.4.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   ```
2. To resolve this issue I downloaded `libapt-pkg.so.4.12` and ran command
   `sudo dpkg -i libapt-pkg.so.4.12.deb` it gives error

   ```
   dpkg: error processing libapt-pkg4.12_1.0.9.7ubuntu4_i386.deb (--install):  cannot access archive: No such file or directory
   Errors were encountered while processing: libapt-pkg4.12_1.0.9.7ubuntu4_i386.deb
   ```

Comment: Please anyone ?

Comment: What is Ubuntu version? When did it start? Your p.2 is incorrect.

Comment: It  started 1 week ago, I dont know if I executed a command I should'nt have.

Comment: What's the output of `apt-get install libapt-pkg4.12`?

Answer (score 1):

Run in terminal

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-pkg4.12_0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.21_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libapt-pkg4.12_0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.21_amd64.deb
```

Comment: dpkg: warning: files list file for package `xkb-data' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.

dpkg: warning: files list file for package `libgtk2.0-common' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.

dpkg: warning: files list file for package `iproute' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.

dpkg: warning: files list file for package `lsb-release' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
(Reading database ... 326872 files and directories currently installed.)

Comment: Preparing to replace libapt-pkg4.12 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.21 (using libapt-pkg4.12_0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.21_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libapt-pkg4.12 ...
dpkg: regarding libapt-pkg4.12_1.0.9.7ubuntu4_i386.deb containing libapt-pkg4.12:i386:
 libapt-pkg4.12:i386 breaks apt (<< 0.9.4~)
  apt (version 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.24) is present and installed.
dpkg: error processing libapt-pkg4.12_1.0.9.7ubuntu4_i386.deb (--install):
 installing libapt-pkg4.12:i386 would break apt, and
 deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)

Comment: OK. Why did you download `i386` package? I fixed the command. But it looks that you have it installed already. You should use the solution only for your architechture `amd64` in the other answer. But you seem to do both.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the deb file for Precise

   ```
   cd; wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-pkg4.12_0.8.16\~exp12ubuntu10.25_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Extract the deb file

   ```
   dpkg -x libapt-pkg4.12_0.8.16\~exp12ubuntu10.25_amd64.deb deb
   ```
3. Copy the files

   ```
   sudo cp deb/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12.0
   ```
4. Create a symbolic link

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12
   ```
5. After the files are available again, your package system will work again. You should re-install the package `libapt-pkg4.12` anyway

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall libapt-pkg4.12
   ```

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 64-bit machine with Intel® Core™ i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4  Processor

Comment: Why not just install the deb by `dpkg -i`?

Comment: @Pilot6 -_- sure :\

Comment: Hey @A.B, Thank you for your reply. I did what you as you said. Everything was fine except the execution of the last command. The last command when executed gives  Error.

Comment: Which error do you mean?

Comment: You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-auth-mysql : Depends: apache2.2-common (>= 2.2.3-3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: @A.B. please remove 32-bit solution. It confused the OP.

Comment: @pilot, I pasted every command for 64 bit machine. I dont't know why it is showing error for 32 bit pkg

Comment: Because you have downloaded `i386` package. Look into your Home folder.

Comment: I remove i386 and run the command, but the same error persist.--------------You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: The following packages have unmet dependencies: libapache2-mod-auth-mysql : Depends: apache2.2-common (>= 2.2.3-3) but it is not going to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: @Abhijeetyadav That's a completely different problem. Try `sudo apt-get install -f` If this doesn't work, ask a new question

Comment: @Pilot6 I have the part removed.

Comment: @A.B. apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: liblz4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory